# daterangepicker with moment js weekend is not clickable

Tags: javascript, momentjs, daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker and moment JS for my date range. The problem here is that the weekends are not clickable. Did I miss a configuration somewhere?

JS Code:

```
$('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
      {
        ranges   : {
          'Today'                : [moment(), moment()],
          'Yesterday'            : [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
          'This Week'            : [moment().day(1), moment().day(5)],
          'This Month'           : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
        },
        startDate: moment(),
        endDate  : moment()
      },
      function (start, end) {
        $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        $("#chosen_range").val(start.format('MM/D/YYYY') + '-' + end.format('MM/D/YYYY'));
      }
    );
```

Comment: According to my JSfiddle it looks its working ? https://jsfiddle.net/dh2gf6qc/

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter It really is a mystery. When I tried to it on a clean page it works but on my current page, it doesn't. [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#cell-editing) has a similar scenario with mine